# Threads listening on TCP and rendering in a loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp

I have two threads, where one listens on TCP and the other renders in a loop:

```
  private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ReceiveCheck.Checked)
                {
                    tcplisten.Start();
                    ListenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));
                    ListenThread.Start();
                    RenderThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Render));
                    RenderThread.Start();

                }
                else
                {
                    tcplisten.Stop();
                    RenderThread.Abort();
                    ListenThread.Abort();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Checkbox");
            }

        }
```

Is this a good way of handling the threads, to just start them and later kill them when I want to?

Comment: Can you clarify this "To just start then, and kill them when i want to?". Are you asking how to do this or is this a good way to do this?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the [**TPL**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)? It's a very nice abstraction and it'll really help you in such cases.

Comment: @Aseem Bansal I am asking if it´s good.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum Never heard of, can you put an answer with what you mean, to display it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is absolutely not a good way. `Thread.Abort()` should never be used, because it is very hard to write correct code when an exception can happen at almost any point in your code.

Instead, you should implement cooperative cancellation either by using a `volatile bool` flag, or, even better, `CancellationToken`.

With that your code could look like this:

```
Thread ListenThread;
Thread RenderThread;
CancellationTokenSource CTS;

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (ReceiveCheck.Checked)
        {
            tcplisten.Start();
            CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
            ListenThread = new Thread(() => Listen(CTS.Token)));
            ListenThread.Start();
            RenderThread = new Thread(() => Render(CTS.Token)));
            RenderThread.Start();
        }
        else
        {
            tcplisten.Stop();
            CTS.Cancel();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Checkbox");
    }
}
```

Your `Listen()` and `Render()` methods would then periodically check `IsCancellationRequested` of the passed in token and return if it's `true`.

Comment: Good to know. Though, never used any of those CancellationToken or volatile bool. Can you show an example?

Comment: @Zerowalker It's not complicated, see update.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn´t work. Am i supposed to implement the IsCancellationRequested myself? in While loop or something?

Comment: @Zerowalker Like I said, you need to check `IsCancellationRequested` yourself. So, if you have a loop in your `Render()` method, then you should check it at the start of each iteration, or something like that.

Comment: if i am supposed to do something like this:                              if (CTS.IsCancellationRequested)
                            {
                                break;
                            } - Why can´t i just use my CheckBox value instead?

Comment: I guess teh difference is that CTS is implemented on each Thread, meaning if i create 10 threads, it will have 10 different CTS. This is good as it will prevent more threads than i want, many thanks:)

Comment: @Zerowalker If you want to cancel all the threads at once, then you can use just one CTS. And you don't want to use your checkbox because of separation of concerns. If you decide to change the checkbox to a button in the future, you don't want to modify `Listen()` and `Render()`, just the event handler.

Comment: isn´t that what you are doing? (putting the CTS in the threads)?, it works perfectly. Very true. But i wonder, is there a way to create and start a thread at the same time, or do i need to use 2 rows (trying to simplify the looks)?

Comment: I dont get how i am supposed to Dispose of the CTS though, if i dispose in the checkbox, it will dispose before the Threads are able to shut down.

Comment: @Zerowalker I think that under most circumstances, it's okay not to dispose the CTS.

Comment: Okay, well i got it working more or less, except i get a dispose error when i dispose on shutdown. So i simply tell the threads to catch and ignore that particular error, which i guess shouldn´t cause any harm.